# react/redux state and components useState become out of sync on fast clicking

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

Edit:formatting of code order:

okay. So I'm trying to track down why this is happening...

the situation is:

I have on component that lists a bunch of divs that are meant to light up green if they are selected... the collection of selected divs is stored in a LogicSlice.producitonMachineSelected[].
and yet if I click to fast - things get... weird.

the component in question is:

```
function MachineCard(props) {
    const data = props.props;
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const [machineCardColor, setMachineCardColor] = useState("#7070ff");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("checkedChanged",checked);
        checked? setMachineCardColor("#70ff70"):setMachineCardColor("#7070ff");

    },[checked])
    return(
        <div className="MachineCard" 
            style={{backgroundColor:machineCardColor}}onClick={()=>{
                setChecked(!checked);
                dispatch(setProductionMachinesSelected(data.machineID))

            }
         }>
       </div>

}
```

the reducer inside logic slice, that was made using CreateSlice from redux toolkit... which allows for immutable update... below is also the immutable code written out by hand... but it results in the same issue... so I'm reasonable sure this is not the source of the bug.

```
        setProductionMachinesSelected:(state,action)=>{
            const machineID = action.payload;
            const found = state.productionMachinesSelected.find(x=>x===machineID);
            if(found){
                state.productionMachinesSelected = state.productionMachinesSelected.filter(x=>x.machineID===machineID)
           }else{
                state.productionMachinesSelected.push(machineID);
           }
            return state;
        }
```

the problem with this code - is the setChecked happens for each dispatch - yet becomes out of sync if clicked too fast.

I have tried putting the dispatch in the useEffect of the machine card

```
//this does not work.
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("checkedChanged",checked);
        checked? setMachineCardColor("#70ff70"):setMachineCardColor("#7070ff");
        dispatch(setProductionMachinesSelected(data.machineID))

    },[checked])
```

I've tried changing the order... but not only does it become out of sync... if clicking to fast... it seems to wipe the producitonMachinesSelected array entirely.

the redux toolkit inspector that manages state also is reflecting these wild changes...

really, I just want to be able to make sure the color of the div matches the state it is in in the redux store... why is this happening?

as for wild changes I mean.

```
the redux state change list
state1: [1]
state2:[1,4,5,6,7,8]
state3:[]
state4:[2,3,4]
state5:[3,4]
state6:[]

// the useState of the components are also doing their own thing independent of this.
```

which I believe should not happen - if each action is actually executed in the order I clicked them, then regardless of how fast I click - shouldn't they be only one state change at a time from the above code? - even if it takes longer to display the cascade of changes?

EDIT: per suggestion tried the following in the reducer:
to no avail: (it's in a create slice from redux toolkit)

```
const machineID = action.payload;
const found = state.productionMachinesSelected.find(x=>x===machineID);
const newState = found?
    {...state,productionMachinesSelected:state.productionMachinesSelected.filter(x=>x.machineID===machineID)}
    :
    {...state,productionMachinesSelected:[...state.productionMachinesSelected, machineID]};
return newState;
```

so... what's happenning?
UPDATE:

revised the pattern to instead of use local state, to read the state from the redux store... this results in the staying in sync with the state... however///

it is still true that if you click fast enough... the state becomes damaged.

double clicking on a div erases the whole array and leaves just that one div in the array...  this is the weird array skipping behavior... this happens regardless of if I write the reducer immutably or not.

Comment: one idea I have to maybe fix the problem? if the issue is in the reducer handling stale updates, instead of an array, an object with keys of the machineID's that just store a bool... so no chance of filter failing... that doesn't scale at all.

Comment: it's using the create slice from redux toolkit, which using immer i think it's called... should be immutable updates... unless array methods don't work?

Comment: and no... rewriting to be 100% immutable by hand... does not change the result at all... still wildly off.

Comment: You dispatch a reducer called setProductionMachinesSelected and in the reducer you mutate state??? The code posted makes no sense. And what is setMachineCardColor? Are you copying redux state to local state and trying to manage both?

Comment: I am using createSlice from reduxTool kit... which uses immer... allowing for state mutating code to be translated to non mutating code. - I have already edited the question with the immutable version - with exactly the same issues, thus I don't believe that's the problem.

Comment: so the component uses a local state to handle it's color. that's all setMachineCardColor is... is from [ machineCardColor,setMachineCardColor]=useState("hex string to apply to div")... no i'm not copying the redux state to local state... let me see if i can edit the question to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

okay... I'm a dumb dumb...

as it turns out... it's not fast clicking at all. it's any clicking to remove an item...

the problem stemmed from two things...

1:i was using two states when i really only needed the one...
2: there was an error in my code in the reducer... i had an array of numbers... but the filter was as if it was an machine object... not a list of MachineId's... thus:

```
            const machineID = action.payload;
            const found = state.productionMachinesSelected.find(x=>x===machineID); 
 
            if(found){
                 state.productionMachinesSelected = state.productionMachinesSelected.filter(x=>x!==found)//here was the error... before it was x.machineID===machineID... the x is a number and not an object

           }else{
                state.productionMachinesSelected.push(machineID);

           }
           state.productionMachinesSelected.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
            return state;
```

now works flawlessly.